# No bell! I don't want ANY bell! Screen on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, gnu-screen, audio

Visual AND audio bells are incredibly annoying. I DON'T CARE that I hit backspace 3 times when there were only 2 characters in the terminal! I KNOW you can't tab-autocomplete because I can see that you HAVEN'T DONE IT!

I want NO BELLS! Of any variety! All the solutions I see online are to turn the visual bell on or off, which inversely turns the audio bell off or on. I want NEITHER BELL!

This is on Ubuntu 12.04 in screen.

**Edit**

It's not the "BEEP!" from the speaker on the motherboard or whatever. It's a "Boink!" sound, clearly a pre-recorded sound effect.

**Edit Edit**

Alright, apparently this question doesn't belong here. In case anyone discovers it on the internet anyway, I got what I wanted by turning off the visual bell (which turns on the audio bell) and then also going to System Settings -> Sound -> Sound Effects -> Selecting both mute check boxes.

Sheesh.

Comment: So it's safe to assume you don't like the bell...

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/15770/what-is-the-best-way-to-turn-off-the-ubuntu-beep-permanently

Comment: @ChrisS Are you trying to tell me this question belongs in superuser?

Comment: @DaveAaronSmith He's telling you that it's a duplicate of a question *from* super user (but yes it does belong in Super User

Comment: Or even on http://askubuntu.com

Comment: @DKNUCKLES Gotcha. Well for what it's worth, I'm not talking about the Ubuntu Beep. I'm talking about the Ubuntu Boink!

Comment: @DaveAaronSmith It's a duplicate of a question on another site, as linked. Unfortunately I can't close as a dupe from other sites. Since it would belong on [SU] I'm supposed to close as "off-topic". Please don't take offense to this, it's just how it is.

Answer (score 3):

try

setterm -blength 0

man setterm

Answer (score 1):

You have two options as far as I can see it

- Manually remove the internal speaker from your motherboard
- [Google some solutions on how to disable the beep permanently](https://superuser.com/questions/15770/what-is-the-best-way-to-turn-off-the-ubuntu-beep-permanently)

Comment: It's not the internal speaker. It's this "Boink!" sound. "Boink! Boink! .... Boink!"

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/15770/what-is-the-best-way-to-turn-off-the-ubuntu-beep-permanently

Comment: If it's not the pc speaker, then you're not just "in screen", you're "in screen in some sort of terminal".  That "some sort of terminal" has the setting for what to do with a bell, for instance PuTTY has an entire screen of options under "Bell".